# How to use KeyValue pair structure in view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

How to use KeyValue pairs (stored in ViewBag/ViewData) in javascript. I Need a KeyValue pair structure say a dictionary from a controller to use in view.

```
ViewBag.ContactTypes = new Dictionary<string,string>
                {
                    {"Home", "5"},
                    {"Cell", "6"},
                    {"Work", "7"},
                    {"Fax", "8"},
                    {"Other", "9"},
                };
```

& I want to access These dictionary values through key like:

```
ViewBag.ContactTypes["Home"]
```

How to achieve this goal, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, I'll delete it if it is not useful.

Inside your controller, I'd use a JsonSerializer (choose your favorite one), and I'd save the Json object into the viewBad :

```
 ViewBag.ContactTypes = YourJsonConverter.serialize(new Dictionnary<string, string>{[...]});
```

And then, use it as a string inside the view :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var myJson = @Viewbag.ContactTypes
 </script>
```

Comment: It won't be a good option to get it in javascript, you can simply use it in views by casting it to Dictionary<string,string> type.

Comment: ooops, its my bad, I didn't read question properly, Sorry @DeblatonJean-Philippe

Comment: Is it possible to combine Javascript code & a server side value like:        var myJson = @Viewbag.ContactTypes.  ??

Comment: ``@Viewbag.ContactTypes`` inside the view will be executed server side. Javascript will be executed client side. That means that once your view has been sent to the client, ``@ViewBag.ContactTypes`` will be replaced by a string that will be parsed by the javascript parser of the client

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your view

First, wrap your Dictionary code in to JSON:

```
ViewBag.ContactTypes = Json(new Dictionary<string,string>
                {
                    {"Home", "5"},
                    {"Cell", "6"},
                    {"Work", "7"},
                    {"Fax", "8"},
                    {"Other", "9"},
                });
```

use bellow javascript in your cshtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
                var data = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ContactTypes)));
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.Data.Home);
</script>
```

Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CBUACN)

Working Fiddle Image [image]

**Suggestion**

If these values are fixed, then instead of fetching it from the server, I would suggest to use Enums at javascript file.
Instead these
    {"Home", "5"},
    {"Cell", "6"},
    {"Work", "7"},
    {"Fax", "8"},
    {"Other", "9"},

Create Enum in somewhere your Common.JS file

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.Enums = function () {
    ContactTypes = {
        Home: 5,
        Cell: 6,
        Work: 7,
        Fax: 8,
        Other: 9,
    };
    Status = {
        CREATED: "CREATED",
        INPROGRESS: "In Progress",
        Completed: { value: 3, name: "Completed", text: "Status Completed" }
    };
    return { Status: Status, ContactTypes: ContactTypes}
}();
```

**USAGE**

```
alert(myApp.Enums.ContactTypes.Home);
```

for better intelligence, just drag your common.js in your transaction JS file.

Comment: fiddle page is not available. I am getting error here:  var data = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ContactTypes)));    as Combining Javascript & server side code.

Comment: What's the error are you getting? try putting break point and verify you're getting correct value.